# Make a link for each string

Tags: php

I have table videos with field tags

```
tags |  word1, word2, word3, word4,
```

And i have this php code that display me tags from each movie

```
    $sql = "SELECT tags FROM videos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$tags='';
while ($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $tags .= $rez['tags'];
    echo str_replace(',', '<br />', $rez['tags']);
}
```

it show me like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

How i can make a link for each word?

I have tried this

```
echo 'http://example.com/'.str_replace(',','</ br>',$rez['tags']);
```

But it show me

```
    http://example.com/word1
    word2
    word3
    word4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your little code bit. See the below code using these you can easily achieve your result.

```
while ($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $array = array_filter(explode(',', $rez['tags']));

  foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo 'http://example.com/' . $value . '<br>';
  }
}
```